# Which column takes preference when sorting by maximum and minimum at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am trying to sort two columns in ascending order at the same time

```
month_summary.sort_values(['max','min'], ascending = [True, True])
```

Returns

```
                min        max        median       mean
MonthYear               
May       156.888715    368.339870  285.927471  282.750633
April     214.224750    403.437916  304.828278  307.117967
January   275.578319    466.011556  384.807907  373.879285
March     282.753506    483.195362  380.308070  377.912478
December  247.545128    486.290301  385.515166  378.210268
February  290.732282    496.484544  400.026110  395.124871
```

The "max" column is sorted in ascending order but the "min" is not. If I reverse the order of the items in the list it does the opposite. I'm curious is that what causes the preference (the list order) on which column gets sorted and if there is a way to sort the columns at the same time in the same data frame?

Comment: The first item in the parameter list is taken to sort the records, then the second. But in your case there is nothing to sort for the second sort criteria. – How could you sort minima and maxima at the same time? Do you want the minima sorted or the maxima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the preference is given to **'max'** column over **'min'** column
Because you give **'max'** as first parameter to `by` in `sort_values()`

```
month_summary.sort_values(['max','min'], ascending = [True, True])
```

In your index named `december` the **'max'** is sorted as usual but due to max column the min column is not sorted but all other columns of **'min'** are sorted in ascending order

And if you write:-

```
month_summary.sort_values(['min','max'], ascending = [True, True])
```

Now It's opposite case

In your index named `december` the **'min'** is sorted as usual but due to min column the max column is not sorted but all other columns of **'max'** are sorted in ascending order

Comment: Thanks Anurag Dabas. Is there a way to sort the month indexes chronologically? So far I have only been able to sort them alphabetically.

Comment: Hey!! between use `df.sort_index(axis=1)` then you will get your desired output i.e all element of min and max columns are arranged in ascending order.....you can sort index alphabetically by `df.sort_index()`....btw what do you mean by chronologically?

Comment: I mean to be able to sort the months in the order they occur so December, January, February, March etc.